# Is there any jquery plugin or technique similar to Whatever:hover htc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Is there any jquery plugin similar to Whatever:hover http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html ?.I'm using jquery library already so is there any jquery plugin to make hover possible on all element in IE 6 like Whatever:hover htc does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the .hover helper in jQuery to add IE6 support (you need to adjust the CSS as well).

Javascript:

```
$('div').hover(function(e) {
  $(e.target).addClass('hover');
},function(e) {
  $(e.target).removeClass('hover');
});
```

CSS:

```
div:hover,div.hover{background:red}
```

Comment: FYI, you could use toggleClass() instead of add/remove class. And $(this) instead of function(e) and e.target.

Comment: do u know any tutorial and example of this

Comment: how to add hover to every tag in once like Whatover:hover does?

Comment: I need a plugin to apply hover on all items without declaring for particular item